# Socket.io Can somebody help me why connected/disconnected message is appearing twice?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Below is my server side code where I want to display if user is connected or disconnected.But the user is connected and user is disconnected message is appearing twice. Can somebody help me why is it appearing twice?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connect', function(socket) {

    socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', 'a user connected!');

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', 'user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', msg);
    });

});


http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Client Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>
<script>
var typing = false;
var timeout = undefined;

function timeoutFunction(){
  typing = false;
  socket.emit(noLongerTypingMessage);
}

function onKeyDownNotEnter(){
  if(typing == false) {
    typing = true
    socket.emit(typingMessage);
    timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 3000);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 3000);
  }
}
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two copies of this in your client file:

```
script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

Remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your order

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {

socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', 'a user connected!');

socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', msg);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', 'user disconnected');
});

});
```

Comment: This does not help. I still see "a user connected!" appearing twice.

Comment: Okay , on `client` side add this  `var socket = io('//localhost:port_no/')` instead of just 'io()'.

Comment: Got it resolved. I was calling  var socket = io(); function twice in the client code.

Comment: Ohh! I had exactly the same problem, instead I was doing the same on server side. Mean calling socket twice on the server side.